# MySQL: for edit a View when use mandatorily `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` or `ALTER VIEW`?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL 8 about Views

- Explicitly about to **edit** a view

I am able to do the following (simple examples):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_to_replace_cc_32 AS SELECT * FROM cuenta_contable cc WHERE cc.code='32';
ALTER             VIEW view_to_alter_cc_32   AS SELECT * FROM cuenta_contable cc WHERE cc.code='32';
```

I confirmed both accomplish the same goal, the edition happens.

The reason of this post is to know under what specific scenario(s) about to edit a view is mandatory one approach over the other. In this case `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` vs `ALTER  VIEW`.

To be honest I had expected only `CREATE VIEW` and `ALTER VIEW`, practically the same combination such as `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE`.

So I am assuming there is a special case for `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`, because I don't remember have seen `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE`.

Comment: This is not really a question with an answer -- one of them creates it if it does not exist and the other throws an error if it does not exist.  End of story.  Tables are different than views and "replacing" tables does not make sense because the table object and the data are not bound in the same way they are with a view.

Comment: mariadb has an create or replace table, sp it is only mysql doesn't have it implemented. Nothing special about it

Comment: @Hogan seems the unique difference is the detection and throw an exception if the view exists or not.

Comment: @ManuelJordan - basically yes.  I don't know about mysql but in other platforms there may be different rights for being able to do one than the other.   An alter might keep the existing ACL in place but replace might not, etc.

Comment: @nbk -- I guess you don't count ms sql server?  There you have to do an if exists on the table.

Comment: ms sql has as far as i know neiteh create or Replace for views nor tables.. I personally use create or repace on mysql and mariadb, but in mssql till now i only needed to alter columns and and some columns, so i look in ms dos for an answer.